# Fubini condition and Brownian motion

Tags: integration, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, expected-value

I know that for being able to apply Fubini I have before to prove the measurability and the integrability condition.
In particular (for what concerne the integrability) I have to prove that:
$$E\bigg[\int_0^t\big| \phi_s \big|ds  \bigg]<\infty$$
and only if this is true I can interchange the two integrals.

Now lets take two example involving the Brownian motion ($B_t$) as integrand:

$1)$ $E\bigg[\int_0^t B_sds \bigg]$

$2)$ $E\bigg[\int_0^t sgn(B_s)ds \bigg]$ where $sgn(x)=1$ if $x \ge 0$ and $sgn(x)=-1$ if $x < 0$.

Is the integrability condition in these cases satisfied? In particular:

Does the continuity of $B_t$ imply that $E\bigg[\int_0^t |B_s |ds \bigg] <\infty?$

Does the fact that $\int_0^t sgn(B_s)ds$ can assume as maximum value $t$ imply that $E\bigg[\int_0^t |sgn(B_s)|ds \bigg]$ is finite?

I would like to understand which are the most common methods for observing that the integrability condition is satisfied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$E\int_0^{t}|B_s|ds=\int_0^{t}E|B_s|ds$ by Tonelli's Theorem. Since $B_s$ has same distribution as $\sqrt s X$ where $X$ has standard normal distribution  we get $E|B_s|=\sqrt sE|X|$.Finally observe that $\int_0^{t} \sqrt s ds <\infty$.

The second is simpler. Use Tonelli's Theorem again and just note that $|sign (B_s)|=1$.

Comment: So what you are actually doing is using Tonelli (interchange for positive function) in the proof of the condition of Fubini, exploiting the fact that we are taking the absolute value of the integrand (becoming a positive function), right? This is very useful, thank you. 1) There are also other common technique used for proving the condition of Fubini's theorem? 2) And therefore is not true that the continuity of $B_t$ imply that $E\bigg[\int_0^t |B_s |ds \bigg] <\infty $, right?

Comment: @Buddy_ continuity of paths is not sufficient. BTW using Tonelli first to show that the hypothesis of Fubini is satisfied is very common.